# in the context of web applications, does implementing REST mean to only use GET requests?

Tags: rest, web-applications

I am trying to better understand the concept of REST. I read the wikipedia article but it's still a bit blurry to me. From what i came to understood, if i need to make my web application REST compliant, i have to :

- use GET requests,avoid POST
- avoid query parameters
- avoid saving session states on the server
- express my application's api using atomic operations

can someone explain more please, in fact an example would be really great!
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the HTTP method is relevant. The key words are "representational" (ie the urls should be representative of the action) and "transfer" (ie the transfer of data between the requestor and the respondor). Parameters are fine too.

Comment: thank you for replying. I understand the URL part now. but how should the data transfer be done?

Comment: HTTP? I'm not being rude I promise, but you need to understand the HTTP pipeline before tackling anything to do with REST. Even me going to this page to view your question is a "data transfer". It's a GET request.